# Variable not updating in Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So in visual studio line goes

```
public float enemySpeed = 0.2f;
```

but in Unity when I change it to lets say `enemySpeed = 1` it stays like that even when I stop "Game" and restart Unity even tho its `enemySpeed = 0.2f` in script.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the value next to the declaration and initialization of the public member won't change in the inspector. Once Unity serialize your public variable, the value is kept until you change it **in the inspector**.

However, if you look at the component, in the inspector, you will see a little gear on the right. Click on it and click on `Reset`. The value you have set in code will be set in the inspector. But be careful, **all your class'members** will be reset too.

[image: Reset]

You can override the [MonoBehaviour's Reset function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html) if you want.

---

An other workaround would be to set your variable `private`, let Unity reserialize your component and put the member back to `public`. (But it may break your code since other scripts may need to reference your class member)

Answer (score 2):

> Changing the value next to the declaration and initialization of the public member won't change in the inspector. Once Unity serialize your public variable, the value is kept until you change it in the inspector.

To add on @Hellium 's answer, you could add the `[System.NonSerialize]` attribute to your variable so it is not serialized.

More on the topic: [[NonSerialized] vs [HideInInspector] question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/199691/nonserialized-vs-hideininspector-question.html)

Example:

```
[System.NonSerialized]
public float enemySpeed = 1;
```

One side effect of this is that you won't be able to change the variable from the inspector anymore, only by script.

Comment: Nice trick! Maybe, putting `[System.NonSerialize]`, letting Unity do his job and removing the attribute afterwards would do the trick?

Comment: Yes, he would have to do this process every time he wants to "reset" the variable. But since he didn't mention he was modifying the variable in the inspector, I think he just needs to add it and his problems will be solved.